# Most well-known set-similarity measures?

Tags: similarities, method-comparison

I know of the [Jaccard index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index) and the [Sørensen-Dice coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%B8rensen%E2%80%93Dice_coefficient) for computing set similarity, but have been unable to find any other algorithms related to set similarity. [This site](https://cals.arizona.edu/classes/rnr555/lecnotes/10.html) contains quite a few resources for vector similarity, but that's not what I want.

What other set-similarity measures exist?

Comment: You can treat being in a set as an variable (or being in the first set as a classifier and being in the second as the concept). Using this reduction you can apply all the supervised learning metrics - accuracy, mutual information, etc.

Answer (score 6):

Other measures are:

- [Overlap Coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlap_coefficient): $\frac{|A \cap B|}{min(|A|,|B|)}$
- [Tversky index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tversky_index): $|A\cap B| + \alpha|A\setminus B| + \beta|B \setminus A|$ where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are positive numbers.

Comment: Tversky is the generalization of Jaccard and DIce