# How to measure similarity between two sets?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, clustering, inference, chi-squared-test, similarities

I want to measure the similarity between sets of images. Every set contains unique image names. The biggest challenge for me is that the sets are not equally sized, and not all images of setA are in setB and vice versa. For example:

setA = {image1, image2, image5, image18, image12}

setB = {image18, image2, image67, image16, image1, image5}

The actual size of these sets are on the order of 10's of thousands. How can I measure the similarity between setA and setB?

Comment: How to do this will depend on what you mean by 'similar'. However, as a guess, I would direct you to the [jaccard index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index).

Comment: Related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/285367/most-well-known-set-similarity-measures